# Which city is the animated show "Street Football" set in?

Tags: street-football

There’s this show "Street Football" about kids that play street soccer. Which city (if any) is the show set in?

Comment: IMDB says it's French/Italian - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1178508/- but very little info on it.

Comment: Indeed! I was wondering city the characters live in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first three seasons of Foot 2 Rue (*Street Football*) follow the adventures of "The Rifflers" a.k.a. "Les Blues de Port Marie". Five of them attend the Riffler Institute in Port Marie, a thinly-veiled representation of [Marseille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marseille).

Main source is [TV tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/Foot2Rue).

As for the city, 1st episode is titled "*Duel dans le vieux port*" (duel in the old port). The old port (*le vieux port* in French) is one of the [most famous and touristic place in the city](https://www.marseille-tourisme.com/en/discover-marseille/culture-heritage/discover-the-sites-and-monuments-in-marseille/the-vieux-port-old-port/). Seems to backup the idea of the city being Port Marie in the show.

Comment: The map shown in episode 4 is a thinly veiled copy of the map of London; https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/e5a76054-5127-4a16-ad45-fe9fe39f0faa/scale-to-width/755 / https://i.stack.imgur.com/fInYt.png